# Emails doesn't work randomly when sending from outside the domain building

Tags: email, exchange-2013

My client has a little bit of an issue with sending Emails via OWA. We use `Exchange 2013`.

When the domain user is staying at a hotel or is in a different state/province in the country, he uses `OWA` for his domain email.

Sometimes, it will work and sometimes it won't. It gives an error: `This message can't be sent right now. Please try again later`.

First I thought, it could be a DNS issue with the location's Internet or it could be the Internet that's blocking the traffic. But then it works sometimes, so I thought that may not be an issue.

This is the only user who travels so I can't be sure if anyone else has that issue. Secondly, we have tried doing basic stuff such as restarting the laptop, restarting services, switching browsers but nothing seems to be working.

How can I fix/debug this issue?